# Retrieving jenkins plugin information in my build logic

Tags: jenkins, plugins

My area is wanting to move our build system to Jenkins and I need to understand more about it. I believe I have a fairly good idea of what I want to do, but not sure of some details.

For example, I want to use the URLTrigger plugin to watch several different areas that could externally trigger the build of a project. The idea is that when one of these URLTriggers happens, my build will then be instantiated by Jenkins.

The build logic would then download a file from that URL location (an Artifactory publish) and do a bit of processing to determine if THIS build needs to continue
(more processing performed, followed by a publish)
or not 
(based on download file contents, it turns out there is nothing to do, so stop).

Is there a way for the build logic to determine WHICH specific URLTrigger-monitored area triggered THIS build? If so, my build logic would only need to download and process that one specific download instead of going to the burden of downloading from ALL of the areas I have configured URLTrigger to monitor.

Comment: After investigating this more I'll attempt to answer my own question...

Answer (score 0):

After investigating this more I'll attempt to answer my own question...

The short answer is "no".

It seems that when you have several resources being monitored by URLTrigger, whenever ANY ONE OR MORE of these resources causes the trigger to fire, it fires and triggers a build.
During the build I can find no way to determine which of the monitored resources actually caused the trigger to fire.
The only way to determine WHY this build was triggered that I can think of is to go to the trouble (and expense) of downloading ALL monitored resources and then determining on my own which ones have changed.
That's a shame, since it seems the URLTrigger would have this information already, and I'm now doing redundant work in the build. Missed opportunities!

Answer (score 0):

Also, since I'll be interrogating these resources at BUILD time, they may have changed since the URLTrigger polling interrogated them, so that seems very poor. I'll need to do some hokey stuff to allow for that I suppose.